# get jquery ui tabs to stop rotating when user clicks on tab or the content

Tags: jquery

I have this script I down loaded for free. I want to cause the script to stop rotating when the user clicks on the tab or page. just down loaded it yesterday and i'm learning css ect... So it dosn't look complete. But stopping it from rotating is a first step.

The site is:
http://gofi.netai.net/

Comment: You would be better to ask this question at stackoverflow, as it's for development questions. You'll likely get a better/faster response.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin is a little better http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ you can even load each tab with AJAX which is nice if you don't want to load all the tabs at once on each page load.